# Change values in dataframe column based on another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've seen a large number of similar questions but nothing quite answers what I am looking to do.

I have two dataframes

- `Conn_df` that contains names and company details manually entered (e.g. `Conn_df["Name", "Company_name", "Company_Address"]`
- `Cleanse_df` that contains cleaned up company names (e.g. `Cleanse_df["Original_Company_Name", "Cleanse_Company_Name"]`

The data for both is held in csv files that are imported into the script.

I want to change the company details in `Conn_df.Company_Name` using the values in `Cleanse_df`, where the `Conn_df.Company_Name` equals the `Cleanse_df.Original_Company_Name` and is replaced by `Cleanse_df.Cleanse_Company_Name`.

I have tried:

`Conn_df["Company"] = Conn_df["Company"].replace(Conn_df["Company"], Cleanse_df["Cleansed"])` but got

> replace() takes no keyword arguments

I also tried:

`Conn_df["Company"] = Conn_df["Company"].map(Cleanse_df.set_index("Original")["Cleansed"])` but got

> Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Any suggestions on how to get the values to be replaced. I would note that both dataframes run to many tens of thousands of rows, so creating a manual list is not possible.

Comment: Does 'Cleanse_df' contain the same company name two or more times?

Comment: The cleanse_df would contain the same company name multiple times in the Cleanse_Company_Name column, but only once in the Original_Company_Name column

Comment: Okay, can you create a small dataset that duplicates you error above?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something along the lines of this:

```
conn_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Mac','K','Hutt'],
                    'Company_name':['McD','KFC','PH'],
                    'Company_adress':['street1','street2','street4']})
cleanse_df = pd.DataFrame({'Original_Company_Name':['McD'],'Cleanse_Company_Name': 
['MacDonalds']})
cleanse_df = cleanse_df.rename(columns={'Original_Company_Name':'Company_name'})
merged_df = conn_df.merge(cleanse_df,on='Company_name',how='left')
merged_df['Cleanse_Company_Name'].fillna(merged_df['Company_name'],inplace=True)
final_df =  merged_df[['Name','Company_adress','Cleanse_Company_Name']]\
    .rename(columns={'Cleanse_Company_Name':'Company_name'})
```

This would return:

```
   Name Company_adress Company_name
0   Mac        street1   MacDonalds
1     K        street2          KFC
2  Hutt        street4           PH
```

You merge the two dataframes and then keep the replaced new value, if there is no value to replace the name then the name will just stay the same, this is done by the fillna command.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Tested it out, and ran in 45 seconds.